# Java UnZipper error?

Tags: java, unzip

I'm making a client updater & I'm getting an error in my cmd whilst trying to unzip the file.

What it's supposed to do is:

- check if the file exists in the user's home (user.home),
- if it doesn't exist in the user's home, check if the file exists in the project's directory,
- if it doesn't exist in the project's directory, download the file; if it does, then unzip the file into the user's home.

The error:

```
 Exists in Directory!
file unzip : C:\Users\Ryan T\Desktop\Rezzion Updater\.rezzion.cache\rezzion.cache
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .rezzion.cache\rezzion.cache\Data (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at rezzion.UnZip.unZipIt(UnZip.java:54)
    at rezzion.Downloader.<init>(Downloader.java:68)
    at rezzion.Downloader.main(Downloader.java:78)
file unzip : C:\Users\Ryan T\Desktop\Rezzion Updater\.rezzion.cache\rezzion.cache\Data
```

Image of Project Folder:
[image]

my Downloader.java (Main Class):

```
    package rezzion;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class Downloader extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static boolean exists = (new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + ".rezzion.cache")).exists();
    private static boolean existsinDir = (new File("rezzion.cache.zip")).exists();
    private static String site = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/yoh4d17gfgnv2od/rezzion.cache.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAE1qdxL_-2y_arb8MBnk8AHSsuhLH1-lwSiGVc0ayQKXA";
    private static String filename = "rezzion.cache.zip";
    private static final String INPUT_ZIP_FILE = "rezzion.cache.zip";
    private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = ".rezzion.cache";
    private final int BUFFER = 1024;

    public Downloader() {
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        JProgressBar current = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        current.setBounds(35, 68, 326, 30);
        current.setValue(0);
        current.setStringPainted(true);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frm.setSize(400, 200);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        if (!exists) {
            if (!existsinDir) {
            frm.getContentPane().add(current);
        try {
            URL url = new URL(site);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            int filesize = connection.getContentLength();
            float totalDataRead = 0;
            java.io.BufferedInputStream in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(filename);
            java.io.BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
            byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER];
            int i = 0;
            while ((i = in.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) >= 0) {
                totalDataRead = totalDataRead + i;
                bout.write(data, 0, i);
                float Percent = (totalDataRead * 100) / filesize;
                current.setValue((int) Percent);
                if (current.getValue() == 99) {
                    current.setValue(100);
                }
            }
            bout.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog((java.awt.Component) null, e.getMessage(), "Error", javax.swing.JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
        }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Exists in Directory!");
            UnZip unZip = new UnZip();
            unZip.unZipIt(INPUT_ZIP_FILE, OUTPUT_FOLDER);
            //TODO: Exists in Directory
        }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Exists in User.Home!");
            //TODO: Exists in User.Home
        }
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Downloader();
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public static void unzipComplete() {
        //TODO
        System.out.println("unzip Complete!");
    }
}
```

My UnZip.java (Self Explanatory):

```
package rezzion;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class UnZip {
    List<String> fileList;
    private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = ".rezzion.cache";

    public void unZipIt(String zipFile, String outputFolder) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {

            // create output directory is not exists
            File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")
                    + OUTPUT_FOLDER);
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }

            // get the zip file content
            ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
                    new FileInputStream(zipFile));
            // get the zipped file list entry
            ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

            while (ze != null) {

                String fileName = ze.getName();
                File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator
                        + fileName);

                System.out.println("file unzip : " + newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

                // create all non exists folders
                // else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
                new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                fos.close();
                ze = zis.getNextEntry();
            }

            zis.closeEntry();
            zis.close();

            System.out.println("Done");
            Downloader.unzipComplete();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the poor formatting of this post, but if anyone can help I've been reading this error for a bit & looking at exactly what it's telling me to, tried merging the classes & no luck. Thanks to those that are willing to point something out, even if it's obvious & I'm missing it.

Comment: As far as I can tell, if it isn't in the directory; you print that it's in the directory (it's in the else to this if `if (!existsinDir) `.

Comment: when I delete it from the directory it doesn't print it. When it's in both directories it prints that it's in both. else if it's not in the directory it downloads & tried to unzip it.. but the unzip gives me that error.

Comment: Yes, but the unzip isn't finding it.

Comment: I got that from the error. "(The system cannot find the path specified)" but I've tried editing the path to the project's directory but it's not working... same error each time.

Comment: What is the full path to the zipfile? And are you 100% sure?

Comment: I provided an image of where the zip file is located. & Yes I'm sure. I've tested the application in every way I could before I added the UnZip.

Comment: That is a relative location.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is apparently a desktop app., the answer seems obvious to me.  For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

> JWS provides many appealing features including, but not limited to, splash screens, desktop integration, file associations, **automatic update (including lazy downloads and programmatic control of updates),** partitioning of natives & other resource downloads by platform, architecture or locale, configuration of run-time environment (minimum J2SE version, run-time options, RAM etc.), easy management of common resources using extensions..

---

> ..is there a way I could just keep this?

No.

- Using automatic updates, you would abandon all that and simply let the JWS client handle it.
- The 'programmatic control of updates' uses an API only available to apps. launched using JWS, specifically the [`DownloadServiceListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadServiceListener.html).

Comment: I'm guessing I'd have to rewrite the program? I've never using JWS so I'm a bit confused on this sorry. I've read the text on the link you've provided & going to continue, but is there a way I could just keep this? I'm new to this feature only used to directly sending the full cache in my client (not zipped) & my client places it into the users home.

Comment: No need to rewrite the program.  Java Web Start will run any program with a `main` method.  The only things you need to do are write a short XML file with a .jnlp extension, and remove (or at least disable) your own automatic updating.